# SQL Server bug or feature? Decimal numbers conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I am experiencing some strange behavior in SQL Server when working with decimal and numeric data types. I have a formula that calculates a specific value (4.250), and I'm using the same rounding and casting operations in all cases. However, I'm getting different results depending on how the value is obtained.

For example, if I get the value from a table, I get a different result than if I get the value from a temporary table, a variable table, or a hardcoded value. The formula is exactly the same in all cases, but the results are different.

I suspect that this is due to differences in how the values are stored or manipulated in each context. Is this a known issue with SQL Server, and is there a way to ensure consistent results across all contexts?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
-- normal table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[value]
(
[val] [decimal] (5, 3) NOT NULL
) 
INSERT INTO [value] VALUES (4.250 )
SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val FROM [value] AS pr

-- inline query from normal table
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val FROM [value] AS pr) a

-- record without table
SELECT ROUND(CAST(4.250 * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val

-- table variable
DECLARE @value AS TABLE (
val  [decimal] (5, 3)
);

INSERT INTO @value VALUES (4.250 )

SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val FROM @value

-- temp table
CREATE TABLE #value
(
    val  [decimal] (5, 3)
)
INSERT INTO #value VALUES (4.250 )
SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val FROM #value AS pr

-- all records together
SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val FROM [value] AS pr
UNION ALL
SELECT ROUND(CAST(4.250 * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val
UNION ALL
SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val FROM @value
UNION ALL
SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val FROM #value AS pr

DROP TABLE #value;
DROP TABLE [dbo].[value];
```

And the results are:

[image]

Comment: FYI - regarding the adding of the new tag, I'm seeing the same behaviour on all versions I have access to, 2008R2 - 2016

Answer (score 14):

This appears to be because you haven't specified the data type of 4.250 everywhere you have hard coded that value, along with mixing datatypes `decimal(5,3)` and `decimal(15,9)` in your table declarations and cast statements.

Note that specifying the same precision everywhere:

```
-- normal table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[value]
  (
     [val] DECIMAL(15, 9) NOT NULL
  )

INSERT INTO [value]
SELECT CAST(4.250 AS DECIMAL(15, 9))

SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val
FROM   [value] AS pr

-- inline query from normal table
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val
        FROM   [value] AS pr) a

-- record without table
SELECT ROUND(CAST(CAST(4.250 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)) * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val

-- table variable
DECLARE @value AS TABLE
  (
     val [DECIMAL] (15, 9)
  );

INSERT INTO @value
SELECT CAST(4.250 AS DECIMAL(15, 9))

SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val
FROM   @value

-- temp table
CREATE TABLE #value
  (
     val [DECIMAL] (15, 9)
  )

INSERT INTO #value
SELECT CAST(4.250 AS DECIMAL(15, 9))

SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val
FROM   #value AS pr

-- all records together
SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val
FROM   [value] AS pr
UNION ALL
SELECT ROUND(CAST(CAST(4.250 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)) * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val
UNION ALL
SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val
FROM   @value
UNION ALL
SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val
FROM   #value AS pr

DROP TABLE #value;

DROP TABLE [dbo].[value];
```

You get the same result for every row:

> 0.003541667

Further Note:

You can test to see what datatype your hardcoded numeric value is by stuffing it into a variant:

```
DECLARE @var SQL_VARIANT;

SELECT @var = 4.250

SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@var, 'BaseType'),
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@var, 'Precision'),
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@var, 'Scale');
```

This returns `numeric(4,3)` on my local SQL Server box. (Numeric and Decimal are the [same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759401/is-there-any-difference-between-decimal-and-numeric-in-sql-server) )

**Edit #2: Further digging**

Taking just the first example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[value]
(
[val] [decimal] (5, 3) NOT NULL
) 
INSERT INTO [value] VALUES (4.250 )

SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val FROM [value] AS pr

-- inline query from normal table
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val FROM [value] AS pr) a

DROP TABLE VALUE
```

Having dug a little further, the execution plans are different - the first statement is being parameterised, whereas the subquery version is not:

[image: execution plans]

If you look at the properties window:

[image]

It doesn't list the datatypes of these parameters, but doing the same trick with stuffing the values `0.01` and `12` into a variant ends up with datatypes `numeric(2,2)` and `int` respectively.

If you cast the hardcoded values in the second statement to those datatypes:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROUND(CAST(val * CAST(0.01 AS NUMERIC(2,2)) / CAST(12 AS INT) AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 9) AS val FROM [value] AS pr) a
```

You get the same result for both statements. Why it has decided to parameterise the select but not the subquery, what the data types of the parameters actually are, and what datatypes the hardcoded values are treated as normally in the second statement...remain a mystery to me. We would probably need to ask someone with internal knowledge of the SQL Server engine.

Comment: I agree it has to do with datatypes. If you change `12` to `12.0` you also get the same results everywhere (`0.003541666`). I still don't really understand  why an inline query would give a different result though.

Comment: I know how get the right results everywhere. You can also multiple val by 0.010000000000 instead of 0.01. However it does not answer why do I have different results when the table definitions are the same?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev I see what you mean - why does selecting against the table return a different value than when you select from the same statement as a subquery...

Comment: I think you are on the right track with the parameterization. If I set the database to `PARAMETERIZATION FORCED`, the subquery is still executed without parameters. If I force parameterization by explicitly using `0.01` and `12` as variables, the returned value is again the same. I think SQL Server defines the parameters in a different datatype than expected. I haven't been able to force the result to `0.003541660` though. [See here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175037(v=sql.105).aspx#Anchor_0)

Comment: @Bridge - this should formalise your findings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql . `When you use the +, -, *, /, or % arithmetic operators to perform implicit or explicit conversion of int, smallint, tinyint, or bigint constant values to the float, real, decimal or numeric data types, the rules that SQL Server applies when it calculates the data type and precision of the expression results differ depending on whether the query is autoparameterized or not. `

Comment: @Alex Looks like a plausible explanation to me - why don't you go ahead and add it as an answer so I can upvote you for it? :)

Answer (score 12):

If I run:

```
SELECT  CAST(pr.val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)) AS val
,       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CAST(pr.val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)), 'BaseType')
FROM    [value] AS pr
```

Value `0.003541660` is returned.

If I run:

```
SELECT  CAST(pr.val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)) AS val
FROM    [value] AS pr
```

Value `0.003541667` is returned.

Smells very much like a bug to me...

**edit**

Based on the answer by Bridge, I too decided to have a look at the execution plans. Lo and Behold:

```
SELECT  CAST(pr.val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)) AS val
FROM    [value] AS pr
OPTION (RECOMPILE)


-- inline query from normal table
SELECT  a.val
FROM    (
            SELECT  CAST(pr.val * 0.01 / 12 AS DECIMAL(15, 9)) AS val
            FROM    [value] AS pr
        ) AS a
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Both queries return `0.003541660`. So it appears the reuse of the execution plan is where the 'error' originates. (Note: `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` doesn't have the same result!)

Extra note: If I save the execution plans as xml, the files are identical both with and without `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`.

**edit:**

If I set the database to `PARAMETERIZATION FORCED`, the subquery is still executed without parameters. If I force parameterization by explicitly using `0.01` and `12` as variables, the returned value is again the same. I think SQL Server defines the parameters in a different datatype than expected. I haven't been able to force the result to 0.003541660 though.
This also explains why `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` results in identical values: If RECOMPILE is used, parameterization is turned [off](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175037(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: I agree there appears to be something funky going on - see my latest edit, anything jump out at you?

Comment: @Bridge, please see my edit. I think we need someone with more in depth knowledge of the inner machinery of SQL Server

Comment: @HoneyBadger - see big red warning here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql

Answer (score 12):

## From [SQL Server data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql) page

> When you use the +, -, *, /, or % arithmetic operators to perform
>   implicit or explicit conversion of int, smallint, tinyint, or bigint
>   constant values to the float, real, decimal or numeric data types, the
>   rules that SQL Server applies when it calculates the data type and
>   precision of the expression results differ depending on whether the
>   query is autoparameterized or not.
>
> Therefore, similar expressions in queries can sometimes produce
>   different results. When a query is not autoparameterized, the constant
>   value is first converted to numeric, whose precision is just large
>   enough to hold the value of the constant, before converting to the
>   specified data type. For example, the constant value 1 is converted to
>   `numeric (1, 0)`, and the constant value 250 is converted to `numeric (3, 0)`.
>
> When a query is autoparameterized, the constant value is always
>   converted to `numeric (10, 0)` before converting to the final data
>   type. When the / operator is involved, not only can the result type's
>   precision differ among similar queries, but the result value can
>   differ also. For example, the result value of an autoparameterized
>   query that includes the expression `SELECT CAST (1.0 / 7 AS float)`
>   will differ from the result value of the same query that is not
>   autoparameterized, because the results of the autoparameterized query
>   will be truncated to fit into the `numeric (10, 0)` data type.

**Note:**

`numeric (10, 0)` is equivalent to `INT`.

In the example above when both dividend and divisor are whole numbers the type is treated as `INT` e.g. `INT` / `INT` = `INT`

If on the other hand one of the types is forced to be a "proper" `NUMERIC` type the expression is treated as `NUMERIC( 10, 0 )` / `NUMERIC( 10, 0 )` = `NUMERIC( 21, 11 )`. See: [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql) for explanation of how result types are calculated.

Example:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT 1 as a, 7 as b, 1 / 7 AS Result'
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT 1 as a, CONVERT( NUMERIC( 10, 0 ), 7 ) as b, CONVERT( INT, 1 ) / CONVERT( NUMERIC( 10, 0 ), 7 ) AS a'
```

**Note:** `NUMERIC` data type only has a fixed number of decimal places (scale) to store fractional numbers. This becomes important when the division produces the result with (infinitely) long decimal part e.g. 1 / 3 that has to be truncated to fit the type.

### Auto-Parameterization

From [Microsoft White Paper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ee343986(v=sql.100)):

> ... only those SQL statements for which parameter values do not affect
>   query plan selection are auto-parameterized.
>
> SQL Server's LPE (Language Processing and Execution) component
>   auto-parameterizes SQL statements. When QP (query processor) component
>   realizes that values of literal constants does not affect query plan
>   choice, it declares LPE's attempt of auto-parameterization "safe" and
>   auto-parameterization proceeds; otherwise, auto-parameterization is
>   declared "unsafe" and is aborted.

If the Query Processor deems the query as "unsafe" the query still executes but the plan that is cached is for that specific query only.

The above article describe in great detail statement types that are ineligible for auto-parametrization.

[SQLTeam](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-parameterization-in-sql-server) article provides a good summary though:

> - Single Table – No JOINs
> - No IN clause
> - No UNION
> - No SELECT INTO
> - No Query Hints
> - No DISTINCT or TOP
> - No full-text, linked servers or table variables
> - No sub-queries
> - No GROUP BY
> - No <> in WHERE clause
> - No functions
> - No DELETE or UPDATE with FROM clause
> - Parameter values can’t affect plan

## OPs case

The difference in results boils down to whether 12 is auto-parameterized and treated as `INT`/ `NUMERIC( 10, 0 )` or not, thus treated as `NUMERIC( 2, 0 )`. This will directly affect the precision (number of decimal places) of the result before rounding: `decimal(19,16)` or `decimal(11,8)`.

Input parameters:

```
-- Note: on my machine "parameterization" option does not have any effect on below example
SELECT CONVERT( decimal (5, 3), 4.250 ) AS a, -- the type is explicitly defined in the table
    0.01 AS b -- always becomes NUMERIC( 2, 2 )
    12 AS c -- will either become NUMERIC( 2, 0 ) or NUMERIC( 10, 0 ) / INT
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT CONVERT( decimal (5, 3), 4.250 ) AS a, 0.01 AS b, 12 AS c'
```

In the above case it is treated as `INT`.

You can "force" it to be treated as `NUMERIC( 2, 0 )`:

```
-- Note: on my machine "parameterization" option does not have any effect on below example
SELECT 0.01 AS b, ( 12 * 0.01 ) AS c
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT ( 12 * 0.01 ) AS c'
-- Result: 0.12 numeric(5,2)
```

Formula for calculating product data type: `p1 + p2 + 1, s1 + s2`.

To find out the starting type solve: `5 = x + 2 + 1, 2 = y + 2` to get `2, 0` i.e. `NUMERIC( 2, 0 )`

Output type of the result will be as follows:

```
-- 12 is NUMERIC( 10, 0 ) / INT
SELECT CONVERT( decimal (5, 3), 4.250 ) * CONVERT( decimal (2, 2), 0.01 ) / CONVERT( decimal(10, 0), 12 )
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT CONVERT( decimal (5, 3), 4.250 ) * CONVERT( decimal (2, 2), 0.01 ) / CONVERT( decimal(10, 0), 12 )'
-- Result: 0.0035416666666666 decimal(19,16) -> rounding to 9 decimal places: 0.003541667

-- 12 is NUMERIC( 2, 0 )
SELECT CONVERT( decimal (5, 3), 4.250 ) * CONVERT( decimal (2, 2), 0.01 ) / CONVERT( decimal(2, 0), 12 )
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT CONVERT( decimal (5, 3), 4.250 ) * CONVERT( decimal (2, 2), 0.01 ) / CONVERT( decimal(2, 0), 12 )'
-- Result: 0.00354166 decimal(11,8) -> rounding to 9 decimal places: 0.003541660
```

To see how the result types are calculated see [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql).

Following the steps described in [Dale Burnett](http://daleburnett.com/2011/08/how-to-tell-if-your-query-has-been-auto-parameterized-and-why-wasnt-it/) article, query plans for every statement in OPs example were obtained. Query plans were checked for `ParameterizedPlanHandle` attribute for each statement. Results are below, with **possible reasons** (see Auto-Parameterization section above) for no Auto-Parameterization:

1. Normal table: Auto-parameterized. Note the following in XML plan: `ParameterizedText="(@1 numeric(2,2),@2 int)SELECT round(CONVERT([decimal](15,9),[val]*@1/@2),(9)) [val] FROM [value] [pr]"`
2. Inline: Did not auto-parameterize. Reason: sub-query. Note that CTEs do not auto-parameterize either.
3. No table: Did not auto-parameterize. Reason: Not sure. Likely too trivial.
4. Table variable: Did not auto-parameterize. Reason: table variable
5. Tempt Table: Did not auto-parameterize. Reason: Not sure. Temp tables are not explicitly mentioned.
6. "All together": Did not auto-parameterize. Reason: `UNION`

### Solution

Cast your literals and / or intermediate results to the desired type to avoid surprises e.g.

```
SELECT CONVERT( decimal( 12, 7 ), CONVERT( decimal (5, 3), 4.250 ) * CONVERT( decimal (2, 2), 0.01 )) / CONVERT( decimal(2, 0), 12 )
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT CONVERT( decimal( 12, 7 ), CONVERT( decimal (5, 3), 4.250 ) * CONVERT( decimal (2, 2), 0.01 )) / CONVERT( decimal(2, 0), 12 )'
-- Result: 0.0035416666 decimal(15,10) -> rounding to 9 decimal places: 0.003541660
```

### Summary

This question is a complex case of: [Division of 2 numbers using CAST function in SQL server 2008R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484434/division-of-2-numbers-using-cast-function-in-sql-server-2008r2). With the complexity stemming from the fact that SQL Server may use different data types in different scenarios.

### Good reads

- [How To Tell If Your Query Has Been Auto-Parameterized (and why wasn’t it?)](http://daleburnett.com/2011/08/how-to-tell-if-your-query-has-been-auto-parameterized-and-why-wasnt-it/)
- [Plan Caching in SQL Server 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ee343986(v=sql.100))

Comment: Very informative answer. However I tried to use sp_describe_first_result_set for the first 2 examples (select val from table and select * from (select val from table)) and I get identical outputs, but the result of the queries is different

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev - you need to remove `CAST` and `ROUND` from your example to see the actual type. Perhaps I did not make it explicit enough in my answer but the difference in result comes from the difference in scale of the result type **before** you apply the final cast.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev - I have updated my answer hopefully it will clear up confusion.

Comment: I can understand why do I have this effect starting from the 3rd example in my question. However it does not explain to me why select * from tbl gives different result than select * from (select * from tbl).

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev - it all depends on SQL Server deciding to parameterize a query. How this desecion making process works is a bit of a mistery. I could find only one article that mentions parameterizion restrictions and it is from 2007.

Comment: @Alex, a more recent [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2013/12/04/how-simple-parameterization-works/)(2013) states: "simple parameterization can only occur if the plan is a trivial plan."

Comment: @HoneyBadger - I checked the article and also checked OP's sample code: for the first two case both plans are "TRIVIAL". It looks like the article is incomplete/misleading. I have found a slightly better article: http://daleburnett.com/2011/08/how-to-tell-if-your-query-has-been-auto-parameterized-and-why-wasnt-it/ . Will need go over both articles in greater detail before I will update the answer again.

Comment: I compared the explain plans (XML) for the first 2 cases and they are identical.