# Assigning values to Null throwing error on decimal type

Tags: sql-server, null, decimal, isnull

Using SQL Server 2016

I am currently supporting an old import routine that wraps lots of dynamic columns with `ISNULL` to tidy up missing data.

The code is generated in dynamic SQL and provides a string in the format of

```
ISNULL(ColumnName, '') ColumnName
```

I have just come across an instance where this has fallen over, i.e. on decimal or numeric columns.  This does however work fine for ints, floats, reals and even dates.  I can introduce more code to replace the `''` with `0` but I don't understand why it works for floats and reals but not decimals or numerics.

As an example have a look at:

```
DECLARE @Test1 AS TABLE (Val FLOAT NULL);           
DECLARE @Test2 AS TABLE (Val INT NULL);             
DECLARE @Test3 AS TABLE (Val REAL NULL);    
DECLARE @Test4 AS TABLE (Val Date NULL);    

DECLARE @TestWillFail AS TABLE (Val DECIMAL(19,6) NULL);   

INSERT INTO @Test1 VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test2 VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test3 VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test4 VALUES (NULL) 
INSERT INTO @TestWillFail VALUES (NULL) 

SELECT ISNULL(Val, '') VAL FROM @Test1;
SELECT ISNULL(Val, '') VAL FROM @Test2;
SELECT ISNULL(Val, '') VAL FROM @Test3;
SELECT ISNULL(Val, '') VAL FROM @Test4;

SELECT ISNULL(Val, '') VAL FROM @TestWillFail;
```

You'll see it works for all cases except decimal (and numeric).

As i said earlier, I can adjust the dynamic sql to look for decimals and numeric columns, but I don't understand "why" it specifically doesn't work in these cases.

Many thanks.

Comment: Interesting... `SELECT ISNULL(cast(Val as varchar),'') VAL FROM @TestWillFail;` works since it makes the entire columns a varchar which your empty string is... where as the other ISNULL is returning 0

Comment: I actually think this might be an XY Problem. Why do you need use `''` for your dynamic SQL in the first place? You say you're using dynamic SQL, but that doesn't explain why. The fact that your dynamic SQL has a clause which tries to convert `''` to a `decimal` says to me that something isn't right.

Comment: @scsimon that's different. `ISNULL` returns a value that has the same datatype as the **first** parameter. The expression would be equivalent to `ISNULL(Val, CAST('' as decimal(19,6)))`, which does fail.

Comment: Almost every question that deals with the oddities of T-SQL can be simply answered with "because consistency was never a design or implementation goal of T-SQL". Why is `SELECT CONVERT(INT, '-')` allowed but not `SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, '-')`? Same answer. `''` will not parse in a conversion to a `DECIMAL` type -- *because*. `''` *will* legally convert to a `DATE` with value `1900-01-01` -- *because*. I doubt even the people implementing this could give you cogent explanations that make sense in all cases.

Comment: @Larnu but why does it convert the int and real and float to 0 implicitly but not the decimal? I'd expect it to. Maybe because REAL isn't precise it doesn't need the decimal... i'm not sure.

Comment: For that, you need to refer to Jeroen's comment, @scsimon; "because".

Comment: Oh, I forgot to test it before, but `CONVERT(DECIMAL, '-')` is perhaps the most bizarre one of all -- it gives "arithmetic overflow" rather than a parsing error. Because of course! I suspect that anyone looking at the code in SQL Server that implements these parsers would have more than a few "what" moments.

Comment: Hi Larnu.  This is code I've inherited.  It's part of an import structure that allows clients to populate a view with their data and we then use that to import into our platform. We have very few decimal fields, and have only recently come across this error.  Since isnull(int,'') resolves to 0 there was no need to check the data type.  As I said, I can (and will) adjust the code to reflect 0 on numeric fields but we try to avoid any overhead that isn't necessary.  Until now, it hasn't been necessary.

Comment: This has been asked before...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729377/sql-server-bug-or-feature-decimal-numbers-conversion

Comment: The bottom line is that the code you inherited is relying on implicit conversion instead of providing a legitimate conversion. What do you want the decimal value to be in this case? 0? I would change the code.

Comment: Think you and I are are thinking along similar lines @SeanLange. Although the OP could handle this by doing something like `ISNULL(Val,0)` for a `decimal`, I think the real problem here is how they're all being handled. I *wonder* if (suspect) the values are being injected into the dynamic SQL, rather than being parametrised.

Comment: Note that "tidying up" values by converting the empty string to whatever it ends up isn't very tidy at all -- I wouldn't consider a `DATE` of `1900-01-01` to be a very good result, for starters. The only value that will definitely convert faithfully in all types, and which makes for an absolutely excellent default for missing values, is `NULL`. If applications then insist on something else to fill in the gaps, they can do so themselves, or have a view for it. (The fact that this is legacy code that probably wouldn't be written this way today (hopefully) notwithstanding.)

Comment: @Larnu yes!!! I would go a step further and do that for ALL the number datatypes.

Comment: Definitely @SeanLange. Why focus on the one that is the causing the error, when in truth implicitly casting and injecting every value is actually a far greater problem. If that is indeed what the OP is doing here (regardless of if it was inherited or not). The question, and format of of their examples does appear to imply that is what's happening.

Comment: @Larnu SeanLange -  Unfortunately there are bigger issues than that with some of the code I've now come across.  These seem to have been converted from old csv file imports, as the same code is there but obviously doesn't affect the data in the same way as it's all text.  There are some Nullable fields which we pull through as null, and some which we then have default constraints in the tables, etc.  I'm slowly unravelling my way through it all.  It will all be tidy one day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ISNULL(check_expression, replacement_value)` returns the same type as *check_expression* ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)). In your examples it is attempting to convert varchar `''` *back to the original datatype*:

```
SELECT CAST('' AS FLOAT)         -- 0
SELECT CAST('' AS INT)           -- 0
SELECT CAST('' AS REAL)          -- 0
SELECT CAST('' AS DATE)          -- 1900-01-01
SELECT CAST('' AS DECIMAL(19,6)) -- Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

The behavior of last example is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> SQL Server also returns an error when an empty string (" ") is
>   converted to numeric or decimal.