# DateAdd side effects?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, casting, dateadd

I am experiencing a very strange behavior here with Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU15):

```
select convert(datetime, max(TS) + 1.0/24) as A 
from table;
```

yields `2021-01-16 11:59:00.000`

while

```
select convert(datetime, max(TS) + 1.0/24) as A
     , dateadd(hour, 1, max(TS)) as B
from table;
```

gives me `2021-01-16 11:58:59.943` for A (and `2021-01-16 11:59:00.000` for B). So, it seems to me that adding the second column changes the result for the first?!

I can force the two-column version to work by casting 1.0 to real, btw: `convert(datetime, max(TS) + cast(1.0 as real)/24)`, but I can **not** force the one-column version to fail by writing `convert(datetime, max(TS) + cast(1.0 as float)/24)`.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Thanks!

Hendrik.

Update: As requested, here is a minimal example:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTS (TS FLOAT);
INSERT INTO TestTS (TS) VALUES (44210.4993055556);

SELECT convert(datetime, max(TS) + 1.0/24) as A
    , dateadd(hour, 1, max(TS)) as B
from TestTS
```

As described, if you comment out the B-column, the value of A changes.

Comment: DATEADD has no side effects. Post a reproducible example: `CREATE TABLE` command, `INSERT` with the actual values, `SELECT` with the query, desired and. actual. values. It's far more likely that the data is wrong or isn't even stored as a date. What's the point of `convert(datetime, max(TS) + 1.0/24)` ?

Comment: BTW `1.0/24` results in an irrational number: `0,04166666666....`. Adding numbers to a date is a hack that only works with `datetime` - only `datetime` can be treated as a number. Floating point operations result in precision issues so you have to assume that adding fractional values will *always* result in inaccurate results. Use `DATEADD` instead

Comment: `DATEADD` isn't wrong. The bug is using `max(TS) + 1.0/24` in the first place

Comment: `1.0/24` returns `0.041666` so this isn't many decimal places retained in the first place, unsurprising you get issues when looking at milliseconds - `0.041666 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` would imply there are only `3599942` milliseconds in a day. Rather than `3600000`

Comment: `1.0` is a  `float` number, so dividing it by an integer will produce a float. You can cast it to a `real` or `decimal`, eg `cast(1 as real)/24`, but this will only reduce the rounding error. 1/24 is irrational so there will *always* be a rounding error. Don't use this technique. Use `DATEADD`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - the literal `1.0` is a `decimal(2,1)` - not a `float`. And `1.0/24` produces a `decimal(7, 6)`

Comment: @MartinSmith I was confused by what you posted that only `0.041666` is returned. Which shouldn't be the case, the last digit should be 7 no matter the precision. SSMS display issue?

Comment: @MartinSmith I can't unsee this, now I have to go test printing with a different number of decimal points.

Comment: not a display issue. the result datatype is `decimal(7, 6)` and `0.041666` is all the digits that can have - there is no room for any other decimal places that are being omitted from display

Comment: @MartinSmith it's even weirder. `1.0/24.0` produces 3 sixes. `1.00/24.00` produces 4 sizes, and any additional fractional `0` produces another digit. So the result's precision if 6 if there are less than 4 fractional digits in total and increases. by 1 for every additional digit. The result is truncated, not rounded, eg `format(1.00/24.000,'N9')` produces `0.041666660`. That may be documented in a remark I never noticed

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I updated the post with a minimal example. My main question is why the behavior for A depends on the presence of B.

Comment: @Ewe Remove the buggy addition. That's the problem.  B is right. A is wrong. If you're lucky, it may produce the same value as B on occasion

Comment: @Ewe now I noticed - you don't have a date to begin with. What are you trying to do in the first place? Dates aren't floats or strings. Use `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset`. Using the wrong type is a major bug

Comment: the resultant scale and precision from dividing two decimals is documented somwehere - the table here is one place https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms190476(v=sql.90) - it's still the same in more recent versions too

Comment: as for the question here. I can reproduce the issue. It compiles a different value into the plan when the second column is there vs when it isn't https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9mEQ.png

Comment: @MartinSmith, it seems that the first query is auto parameterised and the second is not. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45729377/6305294) question sheds some light re what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause

Thanks to @MartinSmith for the clue.

The cause is query auto-parameterization and the data types being chosen to store values.

Query 1 is auto-parameterized:

```
StatementText="SELECT CONVERT([datetime],MAX([TS])+@1/@2)
....
<ColumnReference Column="@2" ParameterCompiledValue="(24)" ParameterRuntimeValue="(24)" />
<ColumnReference Column="@1" ParameterCompiledValue="(1.0)" ParameterRuntimeValue="(1.0)" />
```

Query 2 is **not** auto-parameterized:

```
StatementText="SELECT convert(datetime, max(TS) + 1.0/24) as A...."
```

Why it happens is the first query and not the second query is a bit of a black magic.

From [SQL Server data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql) page:

> When you use the +, -, *, /, or % arithmetic operators to perform
> implicit or explicit conversion of int, smallint, tinyint, or bigint
> constant values to the float, real, decimal or numeric data types, the
> rules that SQL Server applies when it calculates the data type and
> precision of the expression results differ depending on whether the
> query is autoparameterized or not.
>
> Therefore, similar expressions in queries can sometimes produce
> different results. When a query is not autoparameterized, the constant
> value is first converted to numeric, whose precision is just large
> enough to hold the value of the constant, before converting to the
> specified data type. For example, the constant value 1 is converted to
> `numeric (1, 0)`, and the constant value 250 is converted to `numeric (3, 0)`.
>
> When a query is autoparameterized, the constant value is always
> converted to `numeric (10, 0)` before converting to the final data
> type. When the / operator is involved, not only can the result type's
> precision differ among similar queries, but the result value can
> differ also. For example, the result value of an autoparameterized
> query that includes the expression `SELECT CAST (1.0 / 7 AS float)`
> will differ from the result value of the same query that is not
> autoparameterized, because the results of the autoparameterized query
> will be truncated to fit into the `numeric (10, 0)` data type.

### Effect

Based on the above, the following data types are used (refer to See: [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql) for explanation of how result types are calculated):

Query 1 gives higher precision:

```
NUMERIC( 2, 1 ) / NUMERIC( 10, 0 ) = NUMERIC( 13, 12 )
```

Query 2:

```
NUMERIC( 2, 1 ) / NUMERIC( 2, 0 ) = NUMERIC( 7, 6 )
```

### Solution

Cast your literals and / or intermediate results to the desired type to avoid surprises.
In your specific case, best solution is not to use number arithmetic to manipulate dates as Panagiotis Kanavos explains in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65718555/6305294).

Alternatively, forcing float data types (per Dan Guzman comment) `convert(datetime, max(TS) + 1e/24)` would do the trick as well.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45729377/6305294) question deals with the same issue.

Comment: "When a query is autoparameterized, the constant value is always converted to numeric (10, 0) before converting to the final data type." explains it

Comment: The parameter type problem can also be solved with a float literal: `convert(datetime, max(TS) + 1e/24)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. For me as a mere user of a database system, it is sometimes really hard to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with DATEADD. The problem is the rest of the question.

First, there's a critical bug. Dates are stored as floats. An appropriate type should be used instead, eg `datetime2`, `datetime` or `datetimeoffset`. The best options are `datetime2(0)` or `datetimeoffset(0)`, assuming no millisecond precision is needed.

`datetime` is essentially a legacy type, whose internal storage format is ... a float in the OADate format. That doesn't mean floats should be instead of the correct type though, no more than `varbinary` should be used instead of `int` or `bigint`.

Then, there's an attempt to add one hour to the OADate value, by calculating the floating point value of 1 hour in that format, 1/24. That's an irrational number though (0.04166666666....) which means that rounding errors always result in an inaccurate value.

**Solution**

The real solution is to use the correct type and `DATEADD`, eg :

```
CREATE TABLE TestTS (TS datetime2(0));
INSERT INTO TestTS (TS) VALUES ('2021-01-16 10:59:00.000');

SELECT dateadd(hour, 1, max(TS)) as B
from TestTS
```

If you want millisecond precision, use `datetime2(3)`.

**Getting the hack to work.**

If you used `datetime` you wouldn't need to convert to datetime in the end, but the result would still be imprecise. This :

```
declare @TestTS table (TS datetime);
INSERT INTO @TestTS (TS) VALUES ('2021-01-16 10:59:00.000');

SELECT max(ts)+ (1.0/24)
from @TestTS
```

Produces `2021-01-16 11:58:59.943`. The only reason the hack looked to be working in the first place was probably due to rounding errors during conversion.

The only way to get a correct result by adding floating point numbers is to increase precision to 8 fractional digits :

```
declare @TestTS table (TS datetime);
INSERT INTO @TestTS (TS) VALUES ('2021-01-16 10:59:00.000');

SELECT max(ts)+ (1.00000/24)--, dateadd(hour, 1, max(TS)) as B
from @TestTS
```

That produces `2021-01-16 11:59:00.000`.

`1.0` is a decimal(2,1). T-SQL calculates the fractional digits of decimal division based on the functional digits of the operands. If the operands have up to 4 fractional digits, the result will have 6 fractional digits, which isn't enough. 1 digit is added for any fractional digit above 4. `1.00000` results in 8 fractional digits `0.04166666`

Don't do this though.

Comment: Also thanks a lot to you for providing these insights and best practices (although I marked Alex' answer as correct since he digged up the underlying explanation).